# insert node then re-balance avl tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, avl-tree

i'm creating 3 functions that run off of my insert function for my AVL tree class. my rebalance takes the node that is unbalanced and uses my rotate left and rotate right methods depeding on the nodes situation. When i load an avl (avl = AVL()) with the DATA1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and print it using my level order print method it definitly doesnt turn out how its supposed to be. Any of you see where i am going wrong?

```
import copy
from list_array_1 import List

    class _AVLNode:

    def __init__(self, value):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Creates a node containing value.
        Use: node = _AVLNode( value )
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            value - data for the node (?)
        Postconditions:
            Initializes an AVL node containing value. Child pointers are None,
            height is 1.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._value = copy.deepcopy(value)
        # New node is initially added at a leaf.
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._height = 1
        return

    def _update_height(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Updates the height of the current node.
        Use: node._update_height()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            True if node height has been changed, False otherwise.
            _height is 1 plus the maximum of the node's two children.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        old_height = self._height

        if self._left is None:
            left_height = 0
        else:
            left_height = self._left._height

        if self._right is None:
            right_height = 0
        else:
            right_height = self._right._height

        self._height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
        return self._height != old_height

    def _balance(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns the difference in height between the left and right children
        of the current node.
        Use: balance = node._balance()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            balance - difference in height between the left and right children
            of the node. A value of -1, 0, or 1 indicates balance. -2 or less
            the node is unbalanced to the right; 2 or more the node is
            unbalanced to the left. (int)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if self._left is None:
            left_height = 0
        else:
            left_height = self._left._height

        if self._right is None:
            right_height = 0
        else:
            right_height = self._right._height

        balance = left_height - right_height
        return balance

    def __str__(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns a string version of the node. For debugging purposes.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            the contents of the node in the form "h: height, v: value"
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        return "h: {}, v: {}".format(self._height, self._value)

class AVL:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Initializes an empty AVL.
        Use: avl = AVL()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            Initializes an empty avl.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._root = None
        self._count = 0
        self.comparisons = 0
        return

    def is_empty(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Determines if avl is empty.
        Use: b = avl.is_empty()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            True if avl is empty, False otherwise (boolean)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        return self._root is None

    def __len__(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns the number of elements in the AVL tree.
        Use: n = len( avl )
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            the number of values in the AVL tree (int)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        return self._count

    def insert(self, value):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Inserts a new node containing value into the avl.
        The avl may contain only one copy of a value.
        Use: b = avl.insert(value)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            value - the value to insert into the avl (?)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            inserted - True if value has been inserted into the tree,
            False otherwise.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._root, inserted = self._insert_aux(self._root, value)
        return inserted

    def _insert_aux(self, node, value):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Inserts a new node containing value into a new leaf of the avl.
        The avl may contain only one copy of a value. The tree may be
        rebalanced after the insertion.
        Private recursive operation called only by insert.
        Use: node, inserted = self._insert_aux(node, value)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the current node to examine for the existence of
            value (_AVLNode)
            value - the value to insert into the avl (?)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            node - the current node (_AVLNode)
            inserted - True if value has been inserted into the tree,
            False otherwise (boolean)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is None:
            # Base case: create the new node and increment the node count.
            node = _AVLNode(value)
            self._count += 1
            inserted = True
        elif value < node._value:
            # General case: attempt to insert the value to the left.
            node._left, inserted = self._insert_aux(node._left, value)
        elif value > node._value:
            # General case: attempt to insert the value to the right.
            node._right, inserted = self._insert_aux(node._right, value)
        else:
            # Base case: value is already in tree.
            inserted = False

        if inserted:
            # Rebalance the current node if necessary.
            node = self._rebalance(node)
        # Return the node.
        return node, inserted

    def retrieve(self, key):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Retrieves a value matching key in an AVL. (Iterative)
        Use: v = avl.retrieve( key )
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            key - data to search for (?)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            value - the full value matching key, otherwise None (?)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        node = self._root
        value = None

        while node is not None and value is None:
            self.comparisons += 1

            if key < node._value:
                node = node._left
            elif key > node._value:
                node = node._right
            else:
                value = copy.deepcopy(node._value)
        return value

    def _rebalance(self, node):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Rebalances the current node if its children are not balanced.
        Private operation called on insertion and deletion.
        Use: node = self._rebalance(node)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the avl node to rebalance (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            node - the avl node that replaces the original node (_AVLNode)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node._balance() <= -2 and node._right._balance() <= -1:
            node = node._rotate_left(node)
        elif node._balance() >= 2 and node._left._balance() >= 1:
            node = node.rotate_right(node)
        elif node._balance() <= -2 and node._left._balance() >= 1:
            node._right = node._right._rotate_right(node._right)
            node = node._rotate_left(node)
        elif node._balance() >= 2 and node._right._balance() <= -1:
            node._left = node._left._rotate_left(node._left)
            node = node.rotate_right(node)


        return node

    def _rotate_left(self, node):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Rotates the pivot to its left around its right child.
        Updates the heights of the rotated nodes.
        Private operation called on rebalancing.
        Use: node = self._rotate_left(node)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the pivot node to rotate around (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            node - the node that replaces the pivot node (_AVLNode)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        temp = node._right._left
        new_root = node._right
        new_root._left = node
        node._right = temp
        node._update_height()




        return new_root

    def _rotate_right(self, node):

        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Rotates the pivot to its right around its left child.
        Updates the heights of the rotated nodes.
        Private operation called on rebalancing.
        Use: node = self._rotate_right(node)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the pivot node to rotate around (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            node - the node that replaces the pivot node (_AVLNode)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        temp = node._left._right
        new_root = node._left
        new_root._right = node
        node._left = temp

        node._update_height()

        return new_root 
    def __contains__(self, key):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Determines if the AVL contains key.
        Use: b = key in avl
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            key - a comparable data element (?)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            True if the AVL contains key, False otherwise (boolean)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        value = self.retrieve(key)
        return value is not None

    def height(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns the height of the AVL.
        Use: h = avl.height()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            h - the current height of the AVL (int)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if self._root is None:
            h = 0
        else:
            h = self._root._height
        return h

    def inorder(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Prints the contents of the tree in inorder order.
        Use: avl.inorder()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The contents of the tree are printed inorder.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._inorder_aux(self._root)
        return

    def _inorder_aux(self, node):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Traverses node subtree in inorder.
        Private recursive operation called only by inorder.
        Use: self._inorder_aux(node)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - an AVL node (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The children of node are printed inorder.
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is not None:
            self._inorder_aux(node._left)
            print(node._value)
            self._inorder_aux(node._right)
        return

    def postorder(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Prints the contents of the tree in postorder order.
        Use: avl.postorder()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The contents of the tree are printed postorder.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._postorder_aux(self._root)
        return

    def _postorder_aux(self, node):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Traverses node subtree in postorder.
        Private recursive operation called only by postorder.
        Use: self._postorder_aux(node)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - an AVL node (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The children of node are printed postorder.
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is not None:
            self._postorder_aux(node._left)
            self._postorder_aux(node._right)
            print(node._value)
        return

    def preorder(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Prints the contents of the tree in preorder order.
        Use: avl.preorder()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The contents of the tree are printed preorder.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._preorder_aux(self._root)
        return

    def _preorder_aux(self, node):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Traverses node subtree in preorder.
        Private recursive operation called only by preorder.
        Use: self._preorder_aux(node)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - an AVL node (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            prints:
            The children of node are printed preorder.
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is not None:
            print(node._value)
            self._preorder_aux(node._left)
            self._preorder_aux(node._right)
        return

    def is_valid(self):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Determines if an AVL is valid.
        Use: b = avl.is_valid()
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            valid - True if the tree is an AVL, False otherwise.
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        valid = self._is_valid_aux(self._root)
        return valid

    def _is_valid_aux(self, node):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Helper function to determine the AVL validity of node.
        Private operation called only by is_valid.
        Use: b = self._is_valid_aux(node)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the node to check the validity of (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            result - True if node is an AVL, False otherwise (boolean)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is None or (node._left is None and node._right is None):
            # Base case: node is empty or a leaf, so tree must be an AVL.
            result = True
        elif abs(self._node_height(node._left) - \
                 self._node_height(node._right)) > 1:
            # Base case: left or right subtree is too deep.
            print("Height Violation at value: {}".format(node._value))
            result = False
        elif (node._left is not None and node._left._value > node._value) \
            or (node._right is not None and node._right._value < node._value):
            # Base case: does not follow the BST property.
            print("Binary Tree Violation")
            result = False
        else:
            # General case: check the nodes children for validity.
            result = self._is_valid_aux(node._left) and \
                     self._is_valid_aux(node._right)
        return result

    def _node_height(self, node):
        """
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Helper function to determine the height of node - handles empty node.
        Private operation called only by _is_valid_aux.
        Use: h = self._node_height(node)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        Preconditions:
            node - the node to get the height of (_AVLNode)
        Postconditions:
            returns:
            height - 0 if node is None, node._height otherwise (int)
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if node is None:
            height = 0
        else:
            height = node._height
        return height

    def levelorder(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Prints the contents of the tree in levelorder order.
        Use: bst.levelorder()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Postconditions:
          The contents of the tree are printed levelorder.
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        if self._root is not None:
            thislevel = [self._root]
            while thislevel is not None:
                nextlevel = List()
                for n in thislevel:
                    print(n._value)
                    if n._left is not None: 
                        nextlevel.append(n._left)
                    if n._right is not None: 
                        nextlevel.append(n._right)

                thislevel = nextlevel
                print()

                if n._right is None and n._left is None:
                        thislevel = None
```

Comment: would posting my entire AVL class help?

Comment: node._left._baance() : missing a l ?

Comment: I think you do need to show the rest of the class, so that we can test it. Either that or you need to show a bunch of example output, not just say that it's "not how it's supposed to be". What is the output you're getting? What do you expect?

Comment: just included my entire class, i think it has something to do with my rotate left and rotate right methods.

Comment: I've not fully worked through your large quantity of code, but one thing I notice is that you never call the `_update_height` method of your nodes when you add a new value. This results in the `_balance` method returning bad information, and thus `_rebalance` never doing anything.